# Angular/ Firebase - Error message when converting anonymous user to the permanent user ( after user signs in )

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Technology used : Angular 16.2, Firebase 10.4

Scenario:

I am designing a grocery website. I would like the user to start pushing items into the shopping cart with out enforcing them to logging in.

Solution Identified:
Use firebase anonymous authentication for the first time and if the user logs in, then link that user to the anonymous account.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#web-namespaced-api_5

As I am using Typescript, I have added the below code.

convertAnonymousToPermanentUser() {

```
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential("testUser@gmail.com", "testPassword");

console.log("Credential " + JSON.stringify(credential))

this.user$.subscribe(currentLoggedInUser => { // 1. Getting user from AngularFireAuth
  if(currentLoggedInUser) { // ** Anonymous user here
    
    console.log("Current user is " + JSON.stringify(value)) // 2. Logging anonymous user in the console

    // Trying to link user with EmailAuthProvider
    currentLoggedInUser.linkWithCredential(credential).then(userCredential => { // 3. Gives me error
      let user = userCredential.user;
      console.log("Anonymous is upgradee " + JSON.stringify(user))
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Anonymous ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error)) // 4. Logs error in console
    })
  }
})
```

Error Message:

Error logs from the line 4 of above code

Anonymous ERROR {"code":"auth/operation-not-allowed","customData":{"appName":"[DEFAULT]"},"name":"FirebaseError"}

Error message from the network tab of browser:

Request : https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=***

The payload contains the new emailId and password along with other input parameters

Response:
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED : Please verify the new email before changing email.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED : Please verify the new email before changing email.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid"
}
]
}
}

Could some one please help me how to make it work and what is the error message all about?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77175592/unexpected-auth-operation-not-allowed-error-when-linking-anonymous-account-wit